# Ngrx-Entity not using defined DataService on Angular's standalone approach

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity, angular-standalone-components, ngrx-data, angular17

I am currently trying to setup an Angular v17 Repository that uses Ngrx-Store with Ngrx-Entity and Ngrx-Data. I am using the standalone approach. For this, I was following things that were stated in [Github Ngrx Issue #3934](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3934).

The problem is that a registered DataService is not being called as it should be.

I have an EntityService for the User-Entity that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<User> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super(USER_ENTITY_KEY, serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

And I have a Mock-Environment where I want to use a custom *UserDataMock* to get user mocks from a custom JSON file. However, for simplicity I am currently generally injecting and registering this service without a check for the current environment.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDataMockService extends DefaultDataService<User> {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
    super(USER_ENTITY_KEY, http, httpUrlGenerator);
  }

  override getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    console.log('UserDataMockService#getAll called');
    return of([
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Max',
        lastName: 'Mustermann',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Lisa',
        lastName: 'Webb',
      },
    ]);
  }
}
```

I register these two as providers of my AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe, JsonPipe],
  template: `
    <h1>ngrx-data not using mock service</h1>
    <p>
      {{ allUsers$ | async | json }}
    </p> 

  `,
})
export class App {
  allUsers$: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(userEntityService: UserEntityService) {
    this.allUsers$ = userEntityService.getAll();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideStore(),
    provideEntityData(entityConfig, withEffects()),
    provideEffects(),
    provideHttpClient(),

    UserEntityService,
    UserDataMockService,

    {
      provide: ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER,
      useValue() {
        const entityDataService = inject(EntityDataService);
        entityDataService.registerService(
          USER_ENTITY_KEY,
          inject(UserDataMockService)
        );
      },
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
}).catch(console.error);
```

... and this is my *entityConfig*:

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  [USER_ENTITY_KEY]: {},
};

const pluralNames = {};

export const entityConfig: EntityDataModuleConfig = {
  entityMetadata,
  pluralNames,
};
```

Now when running the App, `userDataMockService.getAll` should be called and thus log to the console. But this is not the case.
But it somehow recognizes, that there is another dataService for the user-entity, since removing the UserDataMockService from the providers (also then not registering) results in an error thrown at runtime, because, of course, there is no backend in place and the http-call was not successful.

In my *App*Component I tried to replace `this.allUsers$ = userEntityService.getAll();` with `this.allUsers$ = userEntityService.entities$;`, but without any effect(1).

I created a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5pb8nq?file=src%2Fstore%2Fentity.config.ts)** that reproduces this behavior.

Any help is appreciated!

---

(1) which is pretty clear since the very first call of both should result in the same actions (http-call that then pushes the result into the store) as far as I know